# NFC Tag is null when more than >1 NdefRecord

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

Im a newbie at NFC on Android, but have managed to have an app read & write to a NFC tag.

Originally, I had one NdefRecord in a NdefMessage on the tag, basically some data. I was successful at retrieving the data from the tag whenever I scanned it.

I then wanted to add an application record, so that if user's scan my tag and do not have my app, they are redirected to the PlayStore.

When I introduced the application record to the tag, every time I scan the tag my activity starts/resumes by either `onCreate()` or `onNewIntent()`, I attempt to get the `Tag`, but it is always null. Why is this?

Here is what I write to the tag;

```
Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);      
NdefRecord appRecord = NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.myorg.myapp");
NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA,
        new String("application/com.myorg.myapp")
        .getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")),
        null, "StringData".getBytes());
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { appRecord, record });
if (writeTag(message, detectedTag)) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Success: Wrote placeid to nfc tag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And here is where I read the tag (both in `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`);

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
if(tag!=null) {
    readTag(tag);
}
```

My IntentFilters in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/com.myorg.myapp" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: What intent filters do you use in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NDEF_DISCOVERED intent can only filter for the type of the first record in a tag's NDEF message. Your NDEF message looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| EXT:android:com:pkg | com.myorg.myapp         |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| MIME:application/com.myorg.myapp | StringData |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

So you would need to modify your intent filter to be sensitive to the external type `android:com:pkg`. Or, you move the Android Application Record (AAR) to the end of the NDEF message (that's the prefered way):

```
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { record, appRecord });
```

Which results into this message:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| MIME:application/com.myorg.myapp | StringData |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| EXT:android:com:pkg | com.myorg.myapp         |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

This makes the `application/com.myorg.myapp` record (that you filter for in your manifest) the record used for intent filter matching.

Finally, I would strongly suggest that you use an NFC Forum external type instead of using a custom MIME type. This would have two advantages:

1. The type name in external type names can be significantly more compact (less bytes) than MIME types starting with "application/".
2. You are (due to the domain-based namespace concept) protected from naming conflicts with registered MIME types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this tomorrow morning. I previously had tried switching the the AAR to the end of the NDEF message - I believe that when I scanned the tag on a mobile which did not have my app installed, it would just show the first NDEF Record instead of redirecting to the Play Store. However, I will get back to you tomorrow!